# Can I remove my own question with answers, as duplicate

Tags: support, duplicates

I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869324/openvpn-not-showing-when-trying-to-configure-a-new-vpn) question by searching the site and started a bounty to get the attention of the members. Later I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760664/ubuntu-16-04-openvpn?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is exactly similer as my question and the answer worked for me. Can I close my question?

Answer (score 4):

Because your question has a bounty attached to it, you may not close it at the moment by yourself.

Use the **flag** button on your post to get a moderator's attention. Be sure to select the **in need of moderator intervention** option, and explain *exactly* what you want and why.